# Terraform local-exec doesn't work properly

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am having trouble executing a `terraform` `local-exec`. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Here is the working example

```
resource "null_resource" "web" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
        command  = "mkdir test" 
        working_dir = "/home/jana/io"
  }
}
```

And when I try this, it doesn't work. I need to write some values to a file called `ip.txt` which is already exists.

```
resource "null_resource" "web" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
        command     = <<EOD
    cat <<EOF > ip.txt
[master]
master ansible_host="${aws_instance.kubernetes_master.public_ip}" ansible_user=root
[kubeworkers]
worker1 ansible_host="${aws_instance.kubernetes_minion.0.public_ip}" ansible_user=root
worker2 ansible_host="${aws_instance.kubernetes_minion.1.public_ip}" ansible_user=root
worker3 ansible_host="${aws_instance.kubernetes_minion.2.public_ip}" ansible_user=root
EOF
EOD
  }
}
```

Even when I try something like this, it wouldn't work (that doesn't execute nor I can see any output gives by `terraform apply`)

```
resource "null_resource" "web" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
        command  = "echo 'hellow world' >> ip.txt" 
        working_dir = "/home/jana/io"
  }
}
```

Can someone help me, Please?

**I need to write some values to a text file...**

Comment: If you need to write content to a local file, then you should be using this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/r/file.html

Comment: There's also a [Template provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs) for filling in variables.